# Slick slider moves under other elements

Tags: css, wordpress, slick.js

I have two slick sliders where one of them is the navigation for the other slide.

Slider 1: images (horizontal slider)
Slider 2: text that belongs to the images (vertical slider)

For some reason, slider 2 moves under the title and text that is displayed on top of the element. The slider isn't positioned absolute or something else, so I don't know why this happens

**this is what happens:** the first element moves under the other text

[image: screenshot of the problem]
**url:** https://pauwelsverandas.be/nl/lines/kreativ-line/

Any idea why this occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

div with class slick-track has transform property in css which moves it up

```
transform: translate3d(0px, -53px, 0px);
```

and also don't set the height and width to the elements it is a bad practice

Comment: This code is automatically added, but this did solve my problem